# Is it possible to rewrite a URL with a dot to NOT include the dot using IIS URL Rewrite?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting

I'm using IIS 7.5 with URL Rewrite.

I have old legacy urls out on the web that point to urls like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/games/dog-vs.-cat
http://www.domain.com/games/john.smith-ran-away
```

I need these urls to be rewritten without the dot:

```
http://www.domain.com/games/dog-vs-cat
http://www.domain.com/games/johnsmith-ran-away
```

Here's my rule that is not working.

```
<rule name="RedirectOldURL" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^games/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$" />
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/games/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Is it possible to rewrite the source url without the dot? The dot could appear anywhere in that last piece of url.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In action use

```
<match url="^games/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
```

and in action block use:

```
url="games.aspx?id={R:1}&amp;title={R:2}"
```

Comment: This results in everything after the dot being truncated. 

"dog-vs.-cat" becomes "dog-vs"